# Fat footer in SharePoint

Tags: branding

I am trying to create multi column footer in SharePoint. Could anyone help me to create a fat footer in SharePoint 2010 please?

Answer (score 0):

within your masterpage goto the bottom of the page, just before  tag add a new div

```
    <div id="hfooter" style="padding-bottom: 0px !important; height:100px; width:auto;">
        <!--footer content goes here-->
    </div>
</form>
```

its the div that is the last control, im also sticking it to the bottom of the page and giving it a set height (set what you want), im setting the width to auto.

within the div tag add what you wnat!

Comment: Thank you. It is useful. But, if I want to make it as a Dynamic footer. what should I do?

Comment: how do you mean by dynamic? where would you be getting the info from?

Comment: It has to be from any sharePoint List within the site.

Comment: having it in the master page will reflect on all pages on the site that uses that masterpage!

Comment: Thats fine for me.